# Can I substitute 合适 in place of 量身打造？

Tags: meaning

5万元左右的经济型小车，无疑是为广大工薪阶层量身打造的代步车。

Costing roughly 50 thousand Yuan, a small, economical car is, without a doubt, the most suitable vehicle for the salaried classes

I think I could write 最合适的代步车 instead of 量身打造的代步车， is that correct?

Comment: Of course yes, and note that `为` should be removed at the same time.

Comment: Aha, I did not see that, thanks!

Comment: You can but the meaning becomes different. 为..量身打造 = specially tailored for ..

Comment: Do you really think they mean this car is 'specially made for' the 工薪阶层？If someone's wife wants a little runabout, he probably won't buy her a Ferrari, whatever his income. I thouight more along the lines of 'financially suitable'. We could also say in English 'made to measure'.

Comment: agree with NS.X. The grand picture of the sentence doesn't change, but meaning is a bit different. For an ad, the original way is better.

Answer (score 1):

As lots of the comments have said, Yes, you can make the substitution, but that probably doesn't mean that you should.

The context is obviously an advertisement. It has psychology meanings between the lines. Using words like "Only for you" meant to make the targeted audience felt that they are special.  Of course, we do not really think a 50K RMB car is ONLY made for a special one, neither a $100K customised Tesla, unless it's the so-called Golden Rolls Royce (2.85 billion RMB). But everyone wanted to feel like being THE ONE, and that's why you probably should not replace 量身打造 with 最合适的代步车.

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference between 量身打造 and 最合适的 is that, 量身打造 means this car was designed according to 工薪阶层's requirements and financial conditions, car manufacturers 量身打造 this type of kind to make it 最合适的 for 工薪阶层.

If a car is 量身打造的 for someone, it is also 最合适的 for him/her, while if a car is 最合适的 for someone, it's not necessarily made to measure his/her needs or financial condition, it's just happen to be 最合适的.